# Setting up absolute file path in Golang

Tags: go

I am a package whose only role is to provide a collection of dummy data read from files.

It looks like this:

```
func GetArrayOfSize(n int) []int {
f, _ := os.Open("./arrays.txt")
defer f.Close()

numbers := make([]int, 0)
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)

for scanner.Scan() {
    s, _ := strconv.Atoi(scanner.Text())
    numbers = append(numbers, s)
}

    return numbers[0:n]
}
```

It works fine when I test it inside this package however whenever I call `GetArrayOfSize` from another package I get a runtime error:

```
panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range [recovered]
    panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range
```

I am guessing this error is due to the relative path: `'./arrays.txt`. How can I fetch the absolute path of my `dummy` package to fix this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the error return from os.Open and handle it.

You can get the absolute path to the source code directory using the [go/build](http://godoc.org/go/build) package:

```
p, err := build.Default.Import("github.com/user/repo/dummy", "", build.FindOnly)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
fname := filepath.Join(p.Dir, "arrays.txt")
```

This code assumes that the GOPATH environment variable is set.

Answer (score 0):

Run the **install** command with the **go** tool and you should be able to run your command from anywhere on your system. Here's a good link that gives an example of the **install** command: [How To Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)